# Как работать с DOM без шаблонизаторов?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, dom

Хочу получить значение со страницы из `input` при помощи python, но куда ни глянь - везде используют `Django` или `Jinja2`. Можно ли как-то обойтись без них?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете) Получить значение со страницы можно только в javascript и передать его в серверный код. Шаблонизаторы тут ни при чём.

Comment: Тааакс, @vp_arth, а как тогда передать в python? Пользовался `eel`(точнее баловался XD), там всё легко. А как на серваке это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, есть небольшой html:

```html
<input type="text">
```

С помощью JavaScript мы получаем из него значение:

```js
const value = document.querySelector("input").value;
```

И отправляем его на сервер:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:5000/на_нужный_url', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(value);
})
```

На сервере нужно разрешить CORS с URL сайта.

И уже можно обрабатывать полученные из `input` данные.